# Optimizing "IS NULL"

Tags: optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that is very slow due to a `IS NULL` check in the where clause. At least, that's what it looks like. The query needs over a minute to complete.

Simplified query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 R.TermID2, NP.Title, NP.JID
FROM Titles NP
INNER JOIN Term P
    ON NP.TermID = P.ID
INNER JOIN Relation R
    ON P.ID = R.TermID2
WHERE R.TermID1 IS NULL -- the culprit?
    AND NP.JID = 3
```

I have non-unique, non-clusterd and unique, clustered indices on all of the mentioned fields as well as an extra index that covers `R.TermID1` and has a filter `TermID1 IS NULL`.

Term has 2835302 records. Relation has 25446678 records, where 10% of them has TermID1 = NULL.

The SQL plan in XML form is here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xcDs0VD0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was messing around the index of the largest table, adding filtered indexes, covering columns, changin around the clauses, etc.

At one point I simply deleted the index and created a new index that had the old configuration and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

You could remove the WHERE clause and put the conditions into the JOIN clauses.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 R.TermID2, NP.Title, NP.JID
FROM Titles NP
INNER JOIN Term P
    ON NP.TermID = P.ID AND NP.JID = 3
INNER JOIN Relation R
    ON P.ID = R.TermID2 AND R.TermID1 IS NULL
```

Comment: (Although, I've ran the query only once) it's taking a lot longer than the original query.

Comment: You could compare the plans of these two queries and see if there's any indexes to be optimized.